# Как удалить символы из строки до определенного слова?

Tags: delphi

Приведенный ниже код, удаляет символы в текстовом файле до указанного слова включая первой символ этого слова. Как исправить код, что бы не удалялся первый символ этого слова?

```
var
  f1,f2:TextFile; s:string; p:Word;
begin
  if OpenDialog9.Execute then begin
    AssignFile(f1,OpenDialog9.FileName);
    AssignFile(f2,ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog9.FileName)+'\rez.txt');
    {$i-}
    Reset(f1); Rewrite(f2);
        while not Eof(f1) do begin
            Readln(f1,s);
            repeat
////////////////////////Вот тут не могу понять
            p:=Pos(edit4.Text, s);
            if p<>0 then Delete (s,1, Pos(edit4.Text, s));
            until p=0;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          Writeln(f2,s);
        end;
    CloseFile(f1);
    CloseFile(f2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: а при чем тут регулярное выражение в заголовке вопроса? чтобы первый не удалялся. попробуйте разобраться, кто у вас отвечает за удаление, какие аргументы в эту функцию передаются. быть может там ест длина удаляемой строки? и может ее надо просто уменьшить на 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы еще переписал это:

```
repeat
  p:=Pos(edit4.Text, s); // зачем объявлять переменную
  if p<>0 then Delete (s,1, Pos(edit4.Text, s)); // и не использовать ее???
until p=0;
```

На цикл с предусловием:

```
p := Pos(edit4.Text, s);
while (p <> 0) do
  begin
    Delete (s, 1, p - 1);
    p:=Pos(edit4.Text, s);
  end;
```

Функция `Pos` возвращает номер первого вхождения подстроки, либо `0` если ее ничего не нашла. Соответственно, чтобы не удалять первый символ из подстроки, нужно уменьшить найденный индекс на `1`.

**Upd**: с использованием функции [PosEx](http://www.programm-school.ru/wiki/6_posex-funkciya)

```
last := 0;
p := PosEx(edit4.Text, s, 1);
while (p <> 0) do
  begin
    last := p;
    p := PosEx(edit4.Text, s, p + 1);
  end;
Delete (s, 1, last - 1);
```

Comment: А еще лучше, не обрезать строку в цикле, а сначала найти циклом последнее вхождение подстроки (см. PosEx), а потом за 1 раз обрезать строку.

Comment: @Kromster обновил ответ

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Свои ошибки приняла во внимание. Все заработало благодаря вашей помощи!